# How can I prove this dFa is minimal?

Tags: computer-science, automata, finite-automata, dfa

I am trying prove that this DFA is minimal for this Union.

[image: This is the question and my answer and I am not sure]

Answer (score 4):

You can prove your DFA is minimal by proving that every state is both reachable and distinguishable.

To prove a state `st` is reachable, you must give a word (a possibly empty sequence of symbols) that goes from the starting state (`q0` in your diagram) to state `st`. So for your diagram, you must give six words: one for each of `q0`, `q1`, `q2`, `q3`, `q4`, and `X`. I'll get you started:

| state | word that reaches it from `q0` |
| --- | --- |
| `q0` | "" (the empty word) |
| `q1` | `a` |
| `q2` | `ab` |
| `q3` | *(exercise for the reader)* |
| `q4` | *(exercise for the reader)* |
| `X` | *(exercise for the reader)* |

To prove two states `s1` and `s2` are distinguishable, you must give a word that goes from `s1` to an accepting state and from `s2` to a rejecting state, or vice versa. So for your diagram, you need to provide 6 choose 2 = 15 words: one to distinguish `q0` from `q1`, and one to distinguish `q0` from `q2`, and one to distinguish `q1` from `q2`, and so on. For example, the word `a` distinguishes `q0` from `q3`, because `a` goes from `q0` to `q1` (a rejecting state), but `a` goes from `q3` to `q4` (an accepting state).

I'll get you started:

| state 1 | state 2 | word that distinguishes the states |
| --- | --- | --- |
| `q0` | `q1` | `b` |
| `q0` | `q2` | "" (the empty string) |
| `q0` | `q3` | `a` |
| `q0` | `q4` | `ba` |
| `q0` | `X` | *(exercise for the reader)* |
| `q1` | `q2` | *(exercise for the reader)* |
| `q1` | `q3` | *(exercise for the reader)* |
| `q1` | `q4` | *(exercise for the reader)* |
| `q1` | `X` | *(exercise for the reader)* |
| `q2` | `q3` | *(exercise for the reader)* |
| `q2` | `q4` | *(exercise for the reader but you won't find one)* |
| `q2` | `X` | *(exercise for the reader)* |
| `q3` | `q4` | *(exercise for the reader)* |
| `q3` | `X` | *(exercise for the reader)* |
| `q4` | `X` | *(exercise for the reader)* |

Comment: do you mean that this is the minimal form for that language?

Comment: I do not mean that the diagram posted is a minimal DFA. In fact my answer implies that it is **not** a minimal DFA (see the table entry for `q2`/`q4`).

Comment: Could you show me the diagram of a minimal DFA ?

Comment: @CS_student You may want to have a read through https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6166/294015

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest two ways:

- Perform minimization (perhaps by a computer) and show the number of states is the same.
- Check that all states are reachable and distinguishable, i.e.
  For any state s there is a word w∈Σ∗ such that q0−→ws.
  For each pair (s1,s2) of states present a word w∈Σ∗ such that for s1−→ws′1 and s2−→ws′2 we have s′1 is an accepting state xor s′2 is an accepting state (i.e. s′1∈F⟺s′2∉F).